# Jersey annotation @Path with empty value on class level do not work

Tags: rest, jersey

I declared a rest service by adding @Path("/") on class level and then on method level I declared another @Path("cars"). It doesn't seem to find the service method unless the @Path() on the class level is not empty.
Any ideas why this can't happen?

if the code is like the following

```
@Path("/cars")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface CarService {

    @POST
    void create(Car car);

}
```

it works.

If it is like the below

```
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface CarService {

    @POST
    @Path("/cars")
    void create(CarDto car);

}
```

it doesn't.

Comment: whats the err you are getting or Post your code above so that can have some idea..

Comment: It throws a 404 Not found exception

Comment: Sorry, post your code.

Comment: Since the rest is pattern based representation. Pattern is represented by("/") symbol. having class level directory as("/") is not good.

Comment: It worked. The problem was due to a conflict on paths between class and method.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you should aware while writing resource code,

1.You must use the appropriate method like get,post or put based on operation otherwise it throw 405 error.

2.You must specify a unique path to all otherwise it would conflicts. Having a method name as path name is better idea.

3.You should declare the produce and consume type appropriately.

Good luck, code well.